# How to integrate gmail inbox labels with third-party application?

Tags: gmail-api

We've a custom CRM application for which we have extensions in IBM Notes & MS Outlook, basically our CRM application can be accessed from Notes & Outlook.
In the same way, we would like to extend the application to support through GMail.
Basically, our customers would like to see their custom objects/data inside various labels/folders under GMail inbox.
As per our understanding, this requires some kind of dynamic pulg-in into the GMail inbox. What is the standard/official way of doing this, please suggest.

Thank you,
Shibu.

Answer (score 0):

You can add gadgets inside emails within Gmail.  Basically the user opens an email and can see a pane below the email body.  Full details here

https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

Your concept though of 'non-email' data being available within Gmail under labels is not something I would have thought possible.  Basically labels are applied to emails to allow for organisation of emails only.  I would expect you would need to generate emails to achieve this.

The only way I can think of you achieving such a thing would be to use a Chrome Extension and modify the DOM of Gmail to provide 'custom' labels and objects in the Gmail DOM.

I would suggest you look at using the contextual gadget and allow for search etc from the gadget to allow the user to access the CRM data you speak of.

We have used this technique with our product here - there are some videos which will give you the general idea

http://i3cloud.com/SalesCloudGmail.html

Comment: Thank you so much...!!!
This is very informative and is exactly what I am looking for.
Could you please shed more lights on the implementation...
1. How the user credentials are verified b/w Gmail & the server?
Would you provide a login screen within gmail inbox? Or let the user login from another browser tab and then share that credentials with Gmail?
2. What is the API/programming model used for handling custom forms/objects inside GMail?

Comment: Hi shibu.  You will find all of those answers in the link to contextual gadgets...